# Pinia: $reset alternative when using setup syntax

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I have a pinia store created with setup syntax like:

```js
defineStore('id', () => {
  const counter = ref(0)
  
  return { counter }
})
```

Everything has been working great with setup syntax because I can re-use other pinia stores.

Now, however, I see the need to re-use Pinia stores on other pages but their state needs to be reset.

In Vuex for example, I was using `registerModule` and `unregisterModule` to achieve having a fresh store.

#### So the question is: How to reset the pinia store with setup syntax?

*Note: The `$reset()` method is only implemented for stores defined with the object syntax, so that is not an option.*

*Note 2: I know that I can do it manually by creating a function where you set all the state values to their initial ones*

*Note 3: I found [$dispose](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/pinia._StoreWithState.html#dispose) but it doesn't work. If $dispose is the answer, then how it works resetting the store between 2 components?*

Comment: Reset feature is supported by this library https://github.com/huybuidac/vuex-extensions. Just $store.reset()

Comment: @HuyBuiDac That library is for Vuex, but this question is about Pinia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [Pinia plugin](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html) that adds a `$reset()` function to all stores:

1. On the Pinia instance, call [`use()`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/pinia.Pinia.html#use) with a function that receives a `store` property. This function is a Pinia plugin.
2. Deep-copy `store.$state` as the initial state. A utility like [`lodash.clonedeep`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) is recommended for state that includes nested properties or complex data types, such as `Set`.
3. Define `store.$reset()` as a function that calls [`store.$patch()`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/pinia._StoreWithState.html#patch) with a deep-clone of the initial state from above.
4. We use `Object.assign` to make it work properly with objects [see here](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/2090#issuecomment-1477630404). Same way pinia does itself when [defining `$reset` for Options API](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/blob/v2/packages/pinia/src/store.ts#L329).

```js
// store.js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep'

const store = createPinia()
1️⃣
store.use(({ store }) => {
  2️⃣
  const initialState = cloneDeep(store.$state)
  3️⃣
  store.$reset = () => {
    store.$patch($state => {
      4️⃣
      Object.assign($state, initialState)
    })
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-reset-pinia-store-owsjvm?file=src%2Fstore%2Fplugins%2FstoreReset.js)

---

Feel free to read the article based on this answer: [How to reset stores created with function/setup syntax](https://dev.to/the_one/pinia-how-to-reset-stores-created-with-functionsetup-syntax-1b74)

Comment: `store.$state` is an empty object if you use setup syntax? I am not sure why this is the accepted answer. Is it outdated?

Comment: @oemera Not sure what you mean. The solution works as seen in the linked StackBlitz (although it's possible that code is outdated, as I've not kept up with any recent releases of those libs). If you still need help, I recommend posting a new question with details to reproduce the problem so that someone familiar with the topic can help you. I'll chime in if I can.

Comment: This approach works, however for me it breaks options-api defined stores (I have a mix while we transition to setup func). 

Is there a reliable method to establish if the store is defined via options-api syntax and skip overwriting the `$reset` method? 
Checking if `store.$reset` isn't sufficient, as it's defined on both syntax stores.

Comment: @tivoni To clarify, at the time of the original writing, `$reset` was not a built-in function of the store, and this answer provided a way to define it.

Comment: I realize I did not point out that `$reset` is still not supported with setup syntax, however the property exists, perhaps as a stub only so it logs a "$reset is not supported" message. This makes the store syntax/type difficult to differentiate in an app which combines both setup syntax store and options-api syntax stores

Comment: I found a problem with this. It throws an error when we return a ref as readonly

Comment: I ended up, instead of `prop: readonly(myProp)` I used `prop: computed(() => myProp.value)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as suggested in the documentation [here](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/pinia._StoreWithState.html#dispose)

```
myStore.$dispose()

const pinia = usePinia()

delete pinia.state.value[myStore.$id]
```